# Calculate power of t test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, statistical-power, z-test, type-i-and-ii-errors

I was wondering how you would calculate the power of a one sided and two sided t test and whether it differed from the z test.

I know for a z test it is $p(z < z_{alpha} - abs(u_{a} - u_0)/(s/sqrt(n)))$ for one sided and for two sided you replace the $z_{alpha}$ by $z_{alpha/2}$.

For a t test would it be the same thing but the z_alpha part is replaced by t_alpha or is there something else that differs?

Also on a side not how would you do it in R?
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

To the final question, in R you can use the `pwr` package.  I believe the example below is correct.  I suppose you can compare your results to those for a z-test.

```
### Adapted from
### http://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_02.html

if(!require(pwr)){install.packages("pwr")}

M1  = 100                        # Mean for sample 1
M2  = 110                        # Mean for sample 2
S1  =  15                        # Std dev for sample 1
S2  =  15                        # Std dev for sample 2
N   =  30                        # Number of observations each group

Cohen.d = (M1 - M2)/sqrt(((S1^2) + (S2^2))/2) 

library(pwr)

pwr.t.test(
     n           = N,
     d           = Cohen.d,           
     sig.level   = 0.05,
     power       = NULL,
     type        = "two.sample",
     alternative = "two.sided")
```